# Insert bullets not in enumerate/itemize but within text

Tags: beamer

Consider the following

```
\documentclass[final, 10pt]{beamer} 
\mode<presentation>
{  \usetheme[]{Warsaw}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{title}
  \begin{block}{foo}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item say this
    \item say that
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{block}
  As said in \fbox{1} and described in \fbox{2} \dots
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I would like to have two blue balls instead than the ugly \fbox substitutes.
Is that possible ?

Comment: See if this question answers you: [In Beamer, create a square with a number in it (like enumerate)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37381/2693). If so we can close your question as a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks. It was exactly was I was asking for, albeit not easy to find with "bullet" and "text" in the search engine