# how to specify other symbols for items

Tags: beamer, lists

[image]I want to give a big symbol to my items as titles, how can do that?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\begin{document}
 \begin{itemize}
    \item \textbf{L'algorithme} %my title
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try this:
`\begin{description} \item[L'algorithme] \end{description}`
Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: sorry, but not this, this just make my title in blue, i want to change the item symbol because it's a too small bullet

Comment: Which theme do you use ?

Comment: Mr Munn the solution in link generates lot of errors

Comment: Mr Salim, I use "Madrid" theme

Comment: You can use `\setbeamertemplate{items}[triangle]` or `\setbeamertemplate{items}[square]`.

Comment: @HindDev Sorry, my mistake, I didn't notice you were using `beamer`.

Comment: and beside my title how can I specify? \item [?], my problem is that I have a title of a paragraph, and in the same paragraph I use items so I want for the title something different and bigger

Comment: If you want a numbred items use `enumerate` environment rather then `itemize`.

Comment: I can't use enumerate cause my parts aren't in the same frame

Comment: Related: [Change bullet style / formatting in Beamer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11168) also [beamer: change individual bullet color in itemize list](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14319) and for fancier things [In Beamer, create a square with a number in it (like enumerate)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37381) and [Can one replace bullet points with graphics?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12735).

Comment: On resuming lists in `beamer` see [How to Continue Enumerate Across Columns in Beamer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25710).

Comment: I add a picture

Comment: @Munn I need columns also but it doesn't work for me, I'll try to continu the  enumeration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use  `\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\large $\blacktriangleright$}` to modify labels of items, there are also predefined labels `[triangle]` , `[circle]`, `[square]`,`[ball]`, which can be used like this `\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[ball]`.

**Code**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{madrid}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item \textbf{L'algorithme} %my title
\end{itemize}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\large $\blacktriangleright$}
\begin{itemize}
\item \textbf{L'algorithme} %my title
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've a strange problem, i changed itemize to enumerate like on the link but some frames shows up more than one time !!!

Comment: it work thanks @salim bou, for the frames problem it was the <1-> I deleted it, thank you, but columns doesn't work for me, I don't understand, I'm searching