# Beamer: how can I define circled numbered bullets without using enumitem package?

Tags: beamer

I am using metropolis beamer theme.

Could anyone help me create numbered items with circles around (see pic), but **without** using `enumitem` package, and compatible with `XeLatex` or `Lualatex`?

I figured out how to do it with enumitem, unfortunately it breaks standard bullet points, and I read that enumitem should not be used with beamer.

[image]

Any help appreciated!

Working example (with the `enumitem` solution)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}        
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcommand*{\numberingI}[1]{%
\footnotesize\protect\tikz[baseline=-3px]%
\protect\node[fill=blue,shape=circle,inner sep=2pt](n1){#1};} 

\begin{document}

\section{First Section}
\begin{frame}{}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\numberingI{\color{white}\arabic*}]
   \item firstItem
   \item seconItem
   \item and so on
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37384/2693) can help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure since Alan has directed you to something more complicated, but are you just looking for the `circle` option for the `enumerate items` template? Setting this for `enumerate` won't affect the appearance of `itemize` environments, if that's what you mean by 'standard bullet points'.

[image: numbered items in circles; regular itemise markers]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}        
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[circle]
\setbeamercolor{item projected}{bg=blue,fg=white}
\begin{document}

\section{First Section}
\begin{frame}{}
\begin{enumerate}
   \item firstItem
   \item seconItem
   \item and so on
\end{enumerate}
\begin{itemize}
  \item a
  \item b
  \item c
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Eulerian Oh, good. I almost didn't post, but perhaps Alan Munn was overthinking it ;).

Comment: @cfr Why make it simple when it's so easy to make it complicated. :)

Comment: @AlanMunn Why indeed? By the way, I came up with an answer which combines `forest` with `ext.paths.ortho`.